# Increment char pointer

Tags: c, char, increment

The following code gives a seg fault at second line:

```
 char *tester = "hello";
 char a = (*tester)++;  // breaks here
 printf("Char is %c\n", a);
```

The following code works:

```
 char *tester = "hello";
 a = *tester;
 a++;
 printf("Char is %c\n", a);

 // prints i
```

Why can't it be done in one operation?

Comment: `tester` is a `char *`. `(*tester)` is a constant character. You are trying to increment a constant character.

Answer (score 11):

It can be, you're just incrementing the wrong thing. `(*tester)++` increments the data to which `tester` is pointing. I believe what you wish to do is `*(++tester)` which will increment the pointer and then dereference it.

Comment: Nit: `*(tester++)` evaluates to what `tester` is pointing to *before* the increment; it is logically equivalent to `a = *tester; tester++`.  If you want the second character, you'd write `*(++tester)`.

Comment: I want to increment 'h' to 'i'.

Comment: @JohnBode You are quite right. I've corrected my answer

Answer (score 6):

```
char *tester = "hello";
```

Here tester is pointing to a string constant. It is stored in a read-only memory. Any write modifications causes undefined behavior.

As @Taelsin pointed, it seems you want to increment the pointer itself, and not what it is pointing to. You need *(++tester).

After OP's clarification:

In case you want to increment the H to I, then (*tester + 1) would do the job.

Comment: Thanks.  No I actually want to dereference 'h' and increment it to 'i'.  I guess I don't understand why it's a string constant.  Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Tester is a pointer to a string constant. Like char tester[]="Hello" is different from char *tester = "Hello"

Comment: @CorryChapman In C, string literals like `"hello"` are stored in read-only memory. You can't modify the contents of that string directly. This is why on sufficient warning levels assigning that string literal to a pointer-to-non-const (like you did) will emit warnings. You have to copy the string to a mutable array first if you want to modify the contents: `char tester[] = "hello";`

Comment: @zenith Detail: In C, attempting to write to the address of string literals like `"hello"` is undefined behavior.  C does not define the type of memory in which  `"hello"` is stored.  It _might_ be in read only memory, it _might_ be in writable memory. it may fault.  it is UB.   `"Hello"` is properly called _string literal_.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to increment the character, you can add 1 to it instead of using the increment operator:

```
char *tester = "hello";
char a = (*tester) + 1; // instead of (*tester)++
printf("Char is %c\n", a);
```

Hope this is what you are searching for.

**Explanation**

In another answer, [zenith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425536/zenith) commented an explanation why it is not possible to use the increment operator:

String literals like "hello" are initialized in a read-only memory. It is not possible to increment its value. That is why you have to copy the value first, if you want to change it. `char a = (*tester) + 1;` takes the value of the first character, adds 1 to it and saves it to `a`.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that works, but not clear why it can't be done in one go.  It's a syntax question, rather than looking for a different way to do it.

Comment: @CorryChapman Because `i++` is identical to `i = i+1`, so `i` is changed, while `a = i+1` doesn't change `i`. Why does it matter? `i` is a character of a string literal, and changing it causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`char a = (*tester)++;` does not increase the pointer as you assume; it increases the dereferenced pointer instead, that is, the value a pointer points to.

You are actually trying to make changes to a string literal, which may resides in the read-only memory, causing undefined behaviour.

See n1570, 6.4.5 String literals:

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

To increase the pointer, use `char a = *(tester++);`, or just `char a = *tester++;` thanks to the operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do something like this..

```
const char *tmp = "Hello world. This is a great test";
   int count = strlen(tmp);
   while(count>0)
   {
      printf("%s\n",tmp);
      tmp++;
      count--;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think none of the answers fully answered op's question: op wanted to dereference `'h'` to `'i'`, and he also wanted to know the reason that `segmentFault` came from his first code snippet

Combined above answers/comments, I list a full answer here:

A. op's first confusion comes from the concept difference between `char s[]` and `char *s`:

`char *s="hello";` is to place "hello", the string literal, in the read-only memory and make `s` as a pointer to this string literal, making any writing operation illegal. While if define :

`char s[]="hello";` is to put string literal in read-only memory and **copy** that string to another **allocated memory on the stack**, so that you can read/write directly on the stack memory (still, you are not touching read-only memory).

So dereference to `char *test` will given you a constant char, which is the first letter of a string literal located on read-only memory, that's the reason trying to `char a = (*tester)++` will fail, because this is a pointer operation on read-only memory, the behavior is undefined.

B. why the second code snippet works ?

writing `a = *tester;`  means you declare another variable `char a`, then on stack memory, allocate some space for a `char` and initialize its value to be 'h' ;
This is equivalently to have below:

```
char a;
a = 'h';
```

Of course you can increment `a`.

Here is the example to the explicitly print out the address : [run link](https://onlinegdb.com/SJBJjUVpU)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char * tester = "hello";
    printf("tester first  letter address=%p\n",  tester);       // print out address should be something like 0x400648
    printf("tester second letter address=%p\n", (tester+1));    // print out address should be something like 0x400649

    char a;
    a = *tester;
    printf("a address=%p\n", &a);                               // print out address should be something like 0x7ffe0bc6aab7
    a++;        
    printf("a address=%p\n", &a);                               // print out address should be something like 0x7ffe0bc6aab7

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 char *tester = "hello";
```

you are trying to create a pointer directly to a string here. which will result to unexpected behaviour(because its a read only space)

instead, what I would suggest you is to use **character array**.